# Error when calling method with string: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘size_t&

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to call the method

```
bool someMethod(char const *    begin, char const *     end, size_t & count);
```

having only a string.

```
std::string sString = "test";
if (someMethod(....)) {
   std::cout << "working!";
}
```

But I dont know how to convert the string propertly.

I tried the following:

```
if (someMethod(&sString[0], &sString[sString.length() - 1], sString.length()) {
    std::cout << "working!";
}
```

But I get the following message:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘size_t& {aka long unsigned int&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_string<char>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’
```

Would be awesome if someone has a tipp.

Thank you!

Comment: [A `std::string` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) might help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, AlexM! - what exactly have you tried and what errors do you get? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Consult the author. Only they know why it takes (what seems superfluous to me) `count` parameter by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments and tipps. I edit the question.

Comment: I suspect that `count` is only an "out" parameter returning how many characters between `begin` and `end` where "used", but you should consult the documentation, the author, or the code to find out for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "belt and suspenders" function signature, because it asks both for the end pointer and a count of characters.

In case you are doing it as an exercise, here is what you need to know to complete it:

- you get the pointer to C string inside `std::string` by calling `c_str()`
- you get the count by calling `size()`
- with the initial pointer and size in hand, you get the end pointer by adding the two together.

Note that since size reference is non-const, you need to get it into a variable before making the call:

```
size_t count = s.size();
const char *start = s.c_str();
someFunction(start, start+count, count);
```

Comment: Awesome - that works! Thank you very much! Just one more question: do I have to delete the *start pointer after using it via delete myPointer; //freed memory
myPointer = NULL; //pointed dangling ptr to NULL?

Comment: @AlexM Since the pointer you get via `c_str()` is not a copy of the string's internal buffer but the internal buffer itself, you should not call `delete` on the pointer that you get from `c_str`. The string will call delete on destruction.